# JMeter summariser - interpreting results

Tags: jmeter

I'm struggling to understand how JMeter summariser works:

```
03:06:30 [debug] summary =  73930 in  1523s =   48.5/s Avg:   174 Min:     9 Max: 33133 Err:     4 (0.01%)
03:07:01 [debug] summary +   1573 in  78.2s =   20.1/s Avg:   142 Min:    10 Max:  2428 Err:     1 (0.06%) Active: 1600 Started: 1600 Finished: 0
03:07:01 [debug] summary =  75503 in  1555s =   48.6/s Avg:   173 Min:     9 Max: 33133 Err:     5 (0.01%)
03:07:30 [debug] summary +   1538 in  82.3s =   18.7/s Avg:   118 Min:    10 Max:  2704 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1600 Started: 1600 Finished: 0
03:07:30 [debug] summary =  77041 in  1583s =   48.7/s Avg:   172 Min:     9 Max: 33133 Err:     5 (0.01%)
```

I have 73930 transactions executed in 1523s, which gives average of 48.5/s. Then two bunches of transactions are added on top of that:

1573 in  78.2s =   20.1/s
1538 in  82.3s =   18.7/s

Note the averages - 20.1/s and 18.7/s are below initial 48.5/s. I'd expect those to decrease overall statistics, but it goes up instead, by 0.2/s:

77041 in  1583s =   48.7/s

What I can see is: transactions are added as I'd expect (e.g. 73930 + 1573 = 75503), but how 1523s become 1555s and then 1583 is not clear to me.

Can someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 0):

From the above given logs, it is clear that you have completed the execution of 73930 transactions at 03:06:30. Then  3111(1573+1538) transactions were executed by 03:07:30. So the extra 3111 transactions has taken a time of 60 sec. Which gets added to the original time 1523s. So 1523+60=1583.

It is not summing the time taken for the extra transactions as we sum the extra transactions to the original number of transactions(73930).

You can sum 73930+1573 and then get the total sum as 75503. But you should not sum the time as 1523s+78.2s. The time it is calculating is coming from the original time stamp.

Comment: Well, this is still not clear to me. It looks like 73930 transactions executed in 1523s, while 1573 transactions executed not in 78.2s, but in 30s. This makes mathematics correct, but still doesn't give straightforward answer to what 78.2s stands for. Same column, but different value is presented here.